# Non standard node informations issue (XPath, C code)

Tags: c, xpath, missing-data

I'm using libxml2 (2-2.7.8) and xpath (v1) to extract with my C program some information from wunderground.com generated XML file.
If all nodes contains informations all work great. The problem is when some nodes miss data: if, for example, UV data is unavailable wunderground will apply a syntax like this:

```
<visibility_km>10.0</visibility_km>
<solarradiation>0.1</solarradiation>
<UV/>
<precip_1hr_string>0.00 in ( 0 mm)</precip_1hr_string>
```

causing my XPath to stop navigation and information retrival. My output will be truncated and all data after

```
<UV/>
```

get lost. I guess even my entire program execution stops. Is that a normal behavoiur? How to avoid inconsistence while missing nodes and at least terminate my program execution?

Thanks for help guys, best

Giovanni

My XPath expression:

```
//current_observation/display_location/full | //current_observation/display_location/country_iso3166 | //current_observation/display_location/elevation | //current_observation/observation_location/full | //current_observation/local_time_rfc822 | //current_observation/weather | //current_observation/temp_c | //current_observation/relative_humidity |//current_observation/wind_dir | //current_observation/wind_kph | //current_observation/pressure_mb | //current_observation/feelslike_c | //visibility_km | //current_observation/UV | //current_observation/precip_today_metric | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/date/day | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/date/monthname | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/date/weekday_short | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/date/high/celsius | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/low/celsius | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/date/conditions | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/pop | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/avewind/kph | //simpleforecast/forecastdays/forecastday/avehumidity
```

Part of my code:

```
//code

xmlXPathObjectPtr getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath, char* thisnames) {
    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;    }

    if(xmlXPathRegisterNs(context,  BAD_CAST "new", BAD_CAST thisnames) != 0) {
    printf("Error: unable to register NS with prefix");
    return NULL;    }


    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;    }
    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
        printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;    }
    return result;
}

//code

doc = xmlParseDoc(chunk.memory);
if (doc == NULL ) {
        printf("Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return state;   }
result = getnodeset (doc, xpath, thisnames);
if (result) {
    nodeset = result->nodesetval;
    *myarray = malloc((nodeset->nodeNr + 1) * sizeof(*myarray));
    for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
        keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        (*myarray)[i] = malloc(strlen(keyword)+1);
        if ((*myarray)[i] == NULL) {
        // out of memory.  print error msg then exit
        }
        strcpy((*myarray)[i], keyword);
        printf("id: %d keyword: %s\n",i,keyword);
        xmlFree(keyword);
    }
    xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
    state = i;
}

//code
```

Comment: If the program stops in the middle, you probably have a crash. Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: Sure, here is the error I get:_private CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Comment: If an element is empty and that way has no child nodes then `keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);` is probably not working. I don't know what you want to achieve, if you want to avoid with XPath reading out empty elements you could use e.g. `//current_observation/UV[node()]` instead of `//current_observation/UV`. Of course the same predicate `[node()]` would need to be applied on any element you expect to be empty and don't want to be returned by the XPath evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a libxml2 expert, but looking at your code, I suspect `xmlChildrenNode` is null for the `<UV/>` element, as it has no child-nodes. I don't know what  `xmlNodeListGetString` does if you pass it null, but I'd guess one of two things:

- it segfaults, or
- it returns null back to you, which you're then treating as a string without validation, which will segfault.

To fix it, you should make sure you're validating data that might be null, but for a quick fix, I'd try replacing

```
keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
```

with

```
keyword = xmlNodeGetContent(nodeset->nodeTab[i]);
```